# Use ng-model on Input Field that Has Value Set From Another Model Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have an input field that will be pre-populated with the users info if that data is available (email address, first name, etc.)

I am setting the value of the input field with $scope.userData initially, and when I set an ng-model attribute on the input field the value on the front-end is then blank.

Example:

**Works to show value (input field has users email:**

```
<input class="text-input" type="email" value="{{data.email}}">
```

**Doesn't Work (blank input field):**

```
<input class="text-input" type="email" ng-model="formData.email" value="{{data.email}}">
```

I see why this doesn't work, formData.email is blank and it seems the model will overwrite the value, but I need to save this into formData to then make a POST request to my service upon submission of the form.

I am new to angular and would like to do this with angular rather than using jQuery as a crutch.

**So how would I set the email field to a model to use during form submission, but populate the value of the email field with the initial email data, if present?**

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is execute the following code when the form loads:

`formData.email = data.email`

Angular has the ngInit method for this purpose. Let's say you've set up a function somewhere called initializeEmail which does this. You would then need to add something like this inside your form tag (or anywhere which knows what the formData is):

`<form ng-init="initializeEmail(data.email)>`

Then, when angular loads up it'll see this function and set the formData's email field appropriately.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on ng-load. I added the initEmail function to my controller, so thanks for that idea.

Comment: My bad, ngInit, not ngLoad. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS uses two-way binding.

It means that if you write something in input with `ng-model="formData.email"`, the scope value will change and in controller it will be accessible as `$scope.formData.email`. And if you change the value of `$scope.formData.email` in controller, it will automatically update the value of `<input />` in view.

To set the default address, you should remove the `value` attribute from input and set the value of `$scope.formData.email` in JavaScript at the beginning of controller.

I recommend you to read the official [**basic tutorial**](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). Everything is very well described there.